# Using <pre> Tag in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf

I am using **FPDF** to convert a submitted form in PDF format. On the PDF file, I have a `<pre>` tag. Is there a way to align the text inside the `<pre>` just like the normal output. Below are the example

**Browser output:**

[image: view from chrome]

**PDF Output**

[image: PDF Output]

The code that I use for the FPDF Function is on this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script53.php).

**PHP**

```
$pdf->WriteHTML('<pre>'.$remarks.'</pre>');
```

Is it posible to make the PDF Output as same as the Browser Output.

Comment: Why not use table instead since you're rendering in HTML format?

Comment: That is actually on a `<textarea>` that user input. After click on submit, it will show the PDF regarding the confirmation. Any idea on a better solution?

Comment: Ok, you're allowing the user to format their inputs on the textarea? That would be a problem. I thought its coming from the database.

Comment: There is a validation before submit to database and this is for internal use only.